# Using stb_image's stbi_load

Tags: java, textures, lwjgl, stb-image

I'm using lwjgl's port of `stb_image` to load a `jpg` image. 
Problem is, I always get a `null` to the `ByteBuffer` because nothing gets loaded. 
Here's the code:

```
int[] width = new int[1], height = new int[1], nrChannels = new int[1];

ByteBuffer data = stbi_load("/textures/container.jpg",width, height,nrChannels,0);

if(data == null)
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed to load texture."); //I get this exception.
```

The location of my texture:

[image]

I of course tried it like so:

```
ByteBuffer data = stbi_load("container.jpg",width, height,nrChannels,0);
```

Same result, didn't load. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path you give to stbi_load() is not meant to be a classpath resource but a file system path.